# if statement in js.erb file based on param_name will_paginate (Ajax call)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery, will-paginate

I am trying to work out how to have multiple Ajax calls on the same page (same controller Action) using the will_paginate Gem. So far i have given each instance variable its own param_name so that they are not using the default param of :page

Example Controller

```
@meats= Recipe.meat_recipes.paginate(:page => params[:meat_recipes], :per_page => 1)
@vegrecipes = Recipe.veg_recipes.paginate(:page => params[:veg_recipes], :per_page => 1)
@desserts = Recipe.dessert_recipes.paginate(:page => params[:dessert_recipes], :per_page => 1)
```

Then in the view

```
 <%= will_paginate @meats,  :param_name => 'meat_recipes'  %> (repeat this for individual instance variables)
```

So this part is fine. What i am doing is loading a partial when the AJAX request is made like so

.js.erb file

```
$('#meatRecipes').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'meatrecipes') %>');
$.setAjaxPagination();
```

so at the moment my meat instance variable is working fine. So how to conduct an if statement based on params?

I have tried this for example

```
<% if @meats %>
$('#meatRecipes').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'meatrecipes') %>');
$.setAjaxPagination();
<% end %>

<% if @vegrecipes %>
$('#vegRecipes').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'vegrecipes') %>');
$.setAjaxPagination();
<% end %>
```

Also tried

```
<% if @meats[:param_name] == 'meat_recipes' %>
$('#meatRecipes').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'meatrecipes') %>');
$.setAjaxPagination();
<% end %>

<% if @vegrecipes[:param_name == 'veg_recipes' %>
$('#vegRecipes').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'vegrecipes') %>');
$.setAjaxPagination();
<% end %>
```

but this doesn't work. So i guess my question is what do i use as my argument to ensure that the correct partial is being called for the particular pagination section.

Hope I have explained this correctly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

OK so i need to credit this solution to @karl but this works.. unless anyone has a better way?

```
 <% if params[:meat_recipes] %>
 $('#meatRecipes').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'meatrecipes') %>');
 $.setAjaxPagination();
 <% end %>

 <% if  params[:veg_recipes] %>
 $('#vegRecipes').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'vegeterianrecipes') %>');
 $.setAjaxPagination();
 <% end %>

 <% if  params[:dessert_recipes] %>
 $('#dessertRecipes').html('<%= escape_javascript(render partial: 'dessertrecipes') %>');
 $.setAjaxPagination();
```